# Pre-employment assessment testing

Tags: hiring-process, pre-screening

I have worked in the property management industry (multi-family) for many years.  The industry and hiring practices have changed dramatically.  Many companies are using "People Answers" for pre-employment applications and assessment testing.  The assessment is a typical personality type test which asks the same questions over and again in a different way to see if the applicant is being consistent or deceptive in their answers. I answered it honestly (agree, disagree, strongly agree/disagree etc.).  This assessment stays on file for I believe 2 years so any company using People Answers will get the results of the test if an applicant applies for a position with their company.  The applicants do not get to see any assessment results.

I have applied for several jobs with companies that use People Answers assessments and have not received a call from any of them for an interview.  I have many years experience with great accomplishments but I am over 50.  I have taken all the advice I find online and eliminated anything that could date me on my resume.  However, many of the companies are asking information like Social Security number, year graduated high school etc. which tells them my age.  I am current on software, social media, and other technology used in the industry.  I am frustrated as it seems to eliminate qualified and experienced applicants without even an interview.

Is it likely that either my age or the "People Answers" assessment that's on file is resulting in me not progressing past the initial application stage?

Comment: You don't tell us how long you have been waiting for a call back. I know this is slightly out of the scope of your question - but did you apply to any companies that *don't* use People Answers? If so, did you receive a call back?

Comment: So one company can require you to take this test and other companies have access to the results? This just doesn't sound right.

Comment: It sounds like you're concluding that either your People Answers assessment or your age are the reasons that you don't get calls. Your question focused on the first. However, these are only assumptions - there's no information in the question supporting those assumptions, so I doubt there's anything valuable we can say. Besides, you question ("Any advice, thoughts or information") is way too broad. Can you [edit](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/33595/edit) your text to come up with a more specific question that is answerable?

Comment: Consider starting your own firm

Comment: @JeffO yes, it makes sense. They charge each company the same for the results, but the test-taker only gets one shot. This stops the test-taker from improving the responses each time.

Comment: @bharal - As an employer, that seems like a very weak test.

Comment: Wouldn't your resume be more of an indication of age? Also, how long have you been looking? The "rule of thumb" in a normal economy was 1 month for every $10,000 salary. Depending on your industry that number could be longer or shorter depending on if your job is in demand or not. But generally, the higher your expected salary the longer the job hunt takes. That's why you always need to be aware of the possibility of your company needing to do layoffs and if you might be in that group if they do. If you are, it is best to get looking before it happens. You are more likely to find similar pay.

Comment: Quibble: No economy is ever "normal". You can speak about specific periods, but they all have their own quirks. Inflation rate varies, economic speed varies, pay and pay increases vary. And growth of US$10K/month is definitely *not* normal in most business in most industries.

Comment: There is probably a good question here but it has not been asked yet.  What is it you want to know.  We can not tell you if the results(that we do not know) are affecting your ability to get an interview.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing i can think of is to (falsely, use a different name and hide your identity with a fake email) fill out a form with your qualifications from 10-20 years ago and see if you get any callbacks.

If you do, then the indication is either

1. you are overqualified to what you are applying for or
2. you are right, it is something about ageism.

This won't give you ammunition to action a lawsuit against the company (note that I am *not* a lawyer, maybe it will, if you want to do that then get a lawyer), but will give you some insight into what might be going on.

**If you know any recruiters,** a better bet would be to ask them why the heck you're not getting any "bites" or "nibbles" of interest, and what you might do about that.

Ask them what candidates with your background and experience are getting hired into, and see how their skills and experiences compare to yours. That will be more useful in creating a solution, rather then fretting about what may well be illegal behaviour that you cannot change.

Answer (score -1):

What makes you think that your answers on PeopleAnswers are what gets in the way of your job search? If anything, you should score well there given your experience and the level of social intelligence you acquired over your career. I don't think that your answers you provided in PeopleAnswers are the problem - you don't survive in your industry by being seriously out of touch with the human race :)

You definitely have a problem with getting hired, but I believe that the root of the problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

I would say that of the two, the only one that makes sense to me would be you rated poorly on People Answers.  The reason why is that [age discrimination](http://www.eeoc.gov/laws/types/age.cfm) in the US is illegal.  If a company does something like that then they can be hit with the same type of punishment a liability as other forms of discrimination (race, sex, etc).  That's not to say that it doesn't happen or isn't happening in your case, just that it's not very likely.

If you strongly feel that People Answers might be getting in your way you could always ask prospective employers to let you re-take the assessment.  I don't know how you would necessarily broach the subject as I'm not entirely familiar with the system.  They appear to have a candidate [support](https://www.peopleanswers.com/supportQuestionnaire) department however and I would start there.

Of course there's also the possibility you're running into the standard challenges job seekers face.  Those most common being not as qualified as other candidates, or being over qualified for the posted position.  You may want to analyze the positions you're pursuing and adjust accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately discrimination being illegal doesn't stop it happening. A company doesn't have to give the reason they consider you unsuitable, and they could easily just lie if they did. It's not really enforceable.

Comment: -1 because discrimination happens all the time, and is likely.

Comment: @bharal dirty pool my good man, just because you disagree with one part of my answer does not mean the rest is bad information.  Yes it would be naive to believe that discrimination doesn't happen completely, but in my experience it doesn't happen very often.  Most major companies have made an effort to at least appear to be impartial on numerous aspects of their employment population particularly those that are federally protected.  There is no reason to completely discount the possibility of a bad assessment or inadequate/incompatible skills.